# How do I make a 404 redirect with React Router 6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In React Router 5 I could use a `<redirect path='' />` but that has been removed in React Router 6. I think it's been replaced with `<Navigate>`, but that throws a security error for this use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Redirect` is no longer in the `react-router version 6`. For `react-router-dom v6`, You can use `Navigate` instead of `Redirect`. Here is the example:

```
import {Routes, Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
    return (
        <>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/404" element={<div>Page Not Found/div>} />
                <Route path="*" element={<Navigate replace to="/404" />} />
            </Routes>
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**As of v6:**

- Remove `<Redirect>`s inside `<Switch>`
- Remove any `<Redirect>` elements that are directly inside a `<Switch>`.

```
// Change this:
<Switch>
  <Redirect from="about" to="about-us" />
</Switch>

// to this:
<Switch>
  <Route path="about" render={() => <Redirect to="about-us" />} />
</Switch>
```

- Normal  elements that are not inside a `<Switch>` are ok to remain. They will become `<Navigate>` elements in v6.